# Simple CSV file error when reading

Tags: python, file, csv

I am new to Python programming, I want to know little bit more about the internal working of python, why my code giving this error:

**Code**:

```
with open('countries.csv','r') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        print(row[1])
```

**ERROR:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
2
  File "/DS/main.py", line 12, in <module>
china
    print(row[1])
china
IndexError: list index out of range
germany
us
japan
india
us
china
india
japan

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My CSV file is separated by a simple comma (delimiter), it shows the correct output but with mentioned error?

Comment: Can you add your CSV file contents?

Comment: Python `list`s are 0 indexed.  one of the rows in your file only has one entry.  When you try to access the second entry `print(row[1])` it throws an index error

Comment: us,china,us,sweden,china
canada,china,japan,mexico,us
us,germany,india,india,japan
india,us,us,china,china
england,japan,england,india,japan
mexico,india,china,mexico,us
japan,us,canada,pakistan,india
china,china,us,japan,germany
germany,india,india,china,china
china,japan,china,us,japan

Comment: when I print in for loop like print(row) it works fine but when I try to print row[1] it gives mentioned error

Comment: it has 5 rows, and 50 entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data might contain empty line or row with less than two cells. In order to identify them, use try/except:

```
for row in readCSV:
    try:
        print(row[1])
    except IndexError:
        print('Bad row:', row)
```

## Update

It seems your CSV file has empty lines, which translate to an empty row `[]`. To filter out those empty lines, here is one way to do it:

```
with open('countries.csv','r') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    readCSV = (row for row in readCSV if row) # Filter out empty rows
    for row in readCSV:
        print(row[1])
```

Comment: china
china
germany
us
japan
india
us
china
india
japan
Bad row: []

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: May be you have an empty line in your csv file as it shows `[]` and was caught by `except`.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be

```
with open('countries.csv','r') as csvfile:
readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
for row in readCSV:
    print(row[0])
```

Comment: it is an error because it should have an indentation for with block

Answer (score 0):

While I can't be certain without the SPECIFIC contents of your csv file, I'd recommend `numpy.genfromtxt` Additionally, it could simply be that you don't need to be indexing the 'rows', it may be a 1D dataset (assuming you don't consider the strings themselves to be another dimension).

So:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
acm_data = genfromtxt("countries.csv", delimiter=',', names="country")
countries = acm_data["country"]
for country in countries:
    print(country)
```

EDIT:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
dat = genfromtxt("countries.csv", delimiter=',', names="c1, c2, c3, c4, c5")
countries = sum([tuple(dat["c%d" %i]) for i in range(1,6)], ())
for country in countries:
    print(country)
```

Or if you want to keep it a table, replace `countries = sum([tuple(dat["c%d" %i]) for i in range(1,6)], ())` with `countries = [list(dat["c%d" %i]) for i in range(1,6)]` and replace `print(country)` with `print(country[0])` or `print(country[1])` (if you want to print the first country or second country, respectively).

Comment: ValueError: size of tuple must match number of fields.

Comment: Okay... Maybe delete the `, names="country"` part and assign `countries` directly from `acm_data`

Answer (score 0):

After @Hai Vu:
2nd approach could be:

code:

with open('countries.csv','r')  as  csvfile:

```
    readCSV = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        print(row)
```